# How to format TSV files to use with torchtext?

Tags: csv, pytorch, torchtext

The way i'm formatting is like:

```
Jersei  N
atinge  V
média   N
. PU

Programe    V
...
```

First string in each line is the lexical item, the other is a pos tag. But the empty-line (that i'm using to indicate the end of a sentence) gives me the error `AttributeError: 'Example' object has no attribute 'text'` when running the given code:

```
src = data.Field()
trg = data.Field(sequential=False)
mt_train = datasets.TabularDataset(
    path='/path/to/file.tsv',
    fields=(src, trg))
src.build_vocab(train)
```

How the proper way to indicate EOS to torchtext?

Comment: @kmario23 done!

Comment: You could replace the empty line with 2 `TAB`s.

Comment: @Danny_ds the error is gone but messed up my text/labels. `''` (empty string) appears as a label, for example

Comment: @Bledson Yes, that's normal. To avoid parsing errors, a tsv has to have the same field count on every line. Do you need the empty lines?

Comment: @Danny_ds yes. i need to split sentences as the rnn is fed with batches of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code reads the TSV the way i formatted:

```
mt_train = datasets.SequenceTaggingDataset(path='/path/to/file.tsv',
                                           fields=(('text', text),
                                                   ('labels', labels)))
```

It happens that `SequenceTaggingDataset` properly identifies an empty line as the sentence separator.